# What's the network namespace in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, network-protocols

Can you tell me What's the network namespace in Linux?

And Why need network namespace in Linux?

In Linux network driver, I do not find any related about network namespace.

Is it related with network protocol in Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure this belongs to Stackoverflow but you can take a look at this <http://code.google.com/p/coreemu/wiki/Namespaces> as a starting point

Comment: Got it. But we are some misunderstanding. I raise this question due I have some puzzle on part of Linux kernel code (Networking Part).

Comment: What is your puzzlement?

Comment: My linux is not configured with LXC or any other containers. Do it need networking namespace also?

Answer (score 3):

It's related to container support (e.g. LXC). Each container is like a separate OS, like a virtualized system, but there's still only one kernel. So the kernel needs some way to separate stuff into separate namespaces per container (e.g. PID 1234 in container 1 is not the same process as PID 1234 in container 2). Network namespaces is thus the "containerization" of the network stuff.

Comment: I found it in Linux networking driver. If I do not configure any container in Linux such as LXC, do it need?

Comment: @cnnbcza: I think it's possible to enable network namespaces and use them without containers (in which way that would be useful, I don't know), but only you can know what you need.